# javascript Translate html links into text and keep the url as text

Tags: javascript

OK I have been looking around but not found exactly what I want.
I would like a javascript function that ideally transalate a tag like this

```
<a href="https://www.outlook-apps.com/blog/">
Tips &amp; Tricks – Outlook Tools &amp; Utilities</a>

into this

Tips &amp; Tricks – Outlook Tools &amp; Utilities    
https://www.outlook-apps.com/blog/
```

Is there a library that does this available out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');
const src = a.href;
const sentence = a.textContent;
const parent = a.parentElement;

const text = document.createTextNode(`${sentence} 
${src}`);

window.setTimeout(() => {

  parent.insertBefore(text, a);
  parent.removeChild(a);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<a href="https://www.outlook-apps.com/blog/">
Tips &amp; Tricks – Outlook Tools &amp; Utilities</a>
```

---

#### Legacy

```js
function makeAsText(selector) {
  var a = document.querySelector(selector);
  var src = a.href;
  var sentence = a.textContent;
  var parent = a.parentElement;

  var text = document.createTextNode(
    sentence + '\n' + src
  );

  parent.insertBefore(text, a);
  parent.removeChild(a);
  
}

makeAsText('a');
```

```html
    <a href="https://www.outlook-apps.com/blog/">
    Tips &amp; Tricks – Outlook Tools &amp; Utilities</a>
```

Comment: this looks good, but I cant use jquery unfortunately.  This is jquery right?

Comment: OK thank you, it says templates are not supported.
Not sure what this is to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   
var url="https://www.outlook-apps.com/blog/";  
window.onload = function() {
       //when the document is finished loading, replace everything
       //between the <span> </span> tags with the value of url
   document.getElementById("url").innerHTML=url;
} 
   
</script>
<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/url">
    Tips &amp; Tricks – Outlook Tools &amp; Utilities:         
</a>
<br/><span id="url"></span>
```